# Can I download multiple files to a directory with Flash?

Tags: flash

In Flash, I can prompt the user for a location to save a file and write a file to that location.  In my case, the user wants to download a large set of files.  Is there a way to let the user choose a directory once and download a number of files into that directory without prompting the user for each file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the security sandbox for the Flash Player will not allow for this.  If you can do scripting on the server-side you may want to compress them into a ZIP archive first and then let the user download that single file.

Answer (score 1):

Flash can download files as bytes and then zip them with a library

LIBRARY TO GENERATE ZIP WITH FLASH
http://www.bytearray.org/?p=105

Comment: It should be noted that FileReference.save() will only succeed in response to a mouse click or key press by the user. Unless you have cached the files ahead of time, this approach simply will not work.